# What happened to "attribution required"?

Tags: discussion, attribution

I am sure we all read this right?

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Then why doesn't Jeff Atwood follow this rule in his most recent twitter post?

> http://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/3149290291

This was originally [Pesto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23921/pesto)'s comment:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake/686342#686342

What is going on here?

Comment: can pesto sue atwood? maybe he'll get stackoverflow in the settlement

Comment: @Juan: We could only hope. Finally we would have an answer to our moderation issues.

Comment: @Juan: He'll be hearing from my attorney (Mr. Lionel Hutz, Esq.) in short order.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think it's fairly obvious what is going on here: Jeff is trying to *steal* my comedic genius for his own nefarious purposes.  I am shocked -- **shocked** -- that Jeff would stoop to such levels.  How can we trust *anything* this man says when he so brazenly flaunts his disobedience of the very rules *he* created?

The only **fair** solution is that he turn over complete control of StackOverflow to me.  Actually, I'm not sure that's enough.  We'd better stuff him in a wet burlap bag, string him up by his toes, and *beat* him with a **cane** while we're at it.  Notorious criminal mastermind Jeff Atwood must learn that *actions* have **consequences**.

Comment: I think Welbog would insist we use that occasion to also drive a stake into his heart.

Comment: TheTXI would *Something with a Pony*...

Comment: I think *excessive* use of **formatting** should also have `consequences`.

Comment: @mmyers: *I* **hope** `they're` *sexy* **consequences**.

Comment: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/3151359936

Comment: Just be glad attributions enough and you're not getting charged punitive damages for using a whole 20 words without prior agreement. http://techdirt.com/articles/20090726/1601375666.shtml

Answer (score 10):

Hey man, I had to do all the work to format that damn thing into 140 characters!

Where's *my* credit for that?!?

Comment: I'd twitter you some credit, but i can't stuff it all in 140 characters...

Comment: If I've learned anything from current events, the way to resolve this situation is for Jeff and I to go have a beer with the President.  Only then can the healing begin.

Comment: I'll meet you at the combination Pizza Hut and Taco Bell. http://www.joeydevilla.com/2009/08/05/guilty-pleasure-combination-pizza-hut-and-taco-bell/

Answer (score 2):

That's an ancient quote, I doubt that the originator was the person that put it on stackoverflow...  Not to mention that Twitter causes a 140 char limit that doesn't always allow for the social niceties.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=subclass+of+girlfriend

Comment: First of all, it's *not* an ancient quote.  I do know that I cribbed much of it from a TDWTF forum post I made ages ago, but which I seem to be unable to find now.  It may have been on a deleted post.  However, I'm certain others have come up similar lines (it is obvious, after all), but that one is most certainly mine.  I'm not bothered by it at all, but it does amuse me that Jeff ignored his own rules.

Comment: I think it is certainly a "Pesto original". The only thing I could find that was even remotely (*very* remotely) similar was here: http://www.blakjak.demon.co.uk/prod_wr2.htm

Comment: "Social niceties"! Is it talk like a pirate day again?

Answer (score 2):

Twitter doesn't even allow room for proper links. How could you expect proper attribution? It's nothing short of amazing that he even managed to squeeze the full quote in!

Comment: Perhaps he should not have posted it to twitter then, huh?

Comment: But... Twitter is teh new h0tness!! If it's not twitted, it doesn't properly Exist!

Comment: I believe the correct past-tense is 'twate'.

Answer (score -1):

I can guess:

- He owns the copyright
- There's not enough space in twitter
- Are we sure it's 100% original to Pesto anyway?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=subclass+of+girlfriend

Comment: Let me take your answer point by point.  **Point #1:** I don't think this is accurate (it's all CC-Wiki and requires attribution).  **Point #2:** That's really not a good excuse.  Otherwise I'm reposting everything from SO, 140 characters at a time.  **Point #3:**  It's 100% original to me in the sense that I didn't swipe it from anywhere (see my comment on Brian Knoblauch's post), but I don't claim to be the only one to have ever conceived of it.

Comment: Point 1 is certainly citation-required.  Is there some terms of service document I agreed to where I turned copyright to my words over to Jeff?  I can find no evidence of it.  It's actually all quite vague, but near as I can tell, the implication of posting something on `S[OFU]` is that you're agreeing to license it under cc-attribution-sharealike and that `S[OFU]` is using it under those terms.

Comment: Further material on this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13976/who-owns-the-copyright-to-sofu-content