# When adding image from Wikimedia Commons, automatically add author/license/link

Tags: feature-request, images, legal, licensing, creative-commons

Many Stack Exchange questions and answers embed images from [Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Commons). It is probably the most used image source here.

#### The good news

Thanks to their license, all images from Wikimedia Commons can be legally used inside Stack Exchange.

#### The bad news

The only requirement is to cite the author/license ([example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43908/finding-gilgits-kargah-buddha)), an easy task, but we are totally failing at it. Only maybe 1% of Commons images used here are properly cited. That makes our use of these images illegal, and it could expose Stack Exchange to various legal threats.

*Not my problem*, you could say, but this is also important because [without that we can't claim that Stack Exchange data is open data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262192/140933), bringing Stack Exchange closer to closed-data sites like [Yahoo! Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) or [Experts Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts_Exchange).

#### Proposed solution

When using the image addition widget, the widget should detect whether the image's URL has a `*.wikimedia.org` domain, and if yes:

1. (optional) Transfer the image to [Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur), for perennity reasons.
2. Retrieve the author name and license name from Commons (there is a very reliable API that gives that).
3. Concatenate into a proper citation, maybe something like `"*Credit: [" + author + "](" + commonsPageURL + ") , [" + license + "](" + licenseURL + ")*"`
4. Insert the citation at the same time as the image's Markdown source.

Benefits:

- Avoids a large part of Stack Exchange's copyright violations.
- Makes us a good citizen in the open data world. Remember what happens to sites who disregard ethics (Experts Exchange).
- Consistent citations.
- Zero added burden for the users.

Comment: No problem. However, it means it's quite pointless to add external links to images, as those links will break at some point. Adding the author and license as plain text can be a good idea though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I totally agree, that's why I added Step 1 "*Transfer the image to imgur*" too, even though it is not the main topic :-)

Comment: Yahoo Answers was [closed down in May 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers#Closure). Its [legacy lives on](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed).