# What parts of the site's code and css can I use? (with or without attribution)

Tags: discussion, design

I was wondering what features of the sites I can use - with or without attribution.

Is any of the design (e.g. [the `<kbd>` tags style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260262/is-stackexchanges-kbd-styling-copyrighted)) open?

Comment: This doesn't really have to be related to open source.

Comment: @ShadowWizard <kbd> tag is W3C property rt?

Comment: @Tim are you saying/asking for a official "features list" that Stack Exchange should publish/open source it? I gave an answer for <kbd> tag style: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260262/is-stackexchanges-kbd-styling-copyrighted

Comment: @HackerKarma That's wrong. I'll explain in another answer

Comment: @HackerKarma `<kbd>` tag is part of HTML language. Anyone can use it anywhere, no license or permission is required.