# Stackoverflow copy rights

Tags: discussion, copyright

If someone builds another product like Stack Overflow, can they be sued for some kind of patent/copyright infringement?

If yes, which parts of Stack Overflow design cannot be copied.

Comment: There are already several like [gateoverflow.in](http://gateoverflow.in/),etc...

Comment: @shekharsuman that's an intersting find... it even has "overflow" keyword in it.

Comment: @HackerKarma-Actually, in India here guys who have done undergraduation in CS, applying for MS/M.Tech(also available in India) have to go through this GATE examination. So, a group of guys developed this website for helping those questioner getting answered questions related to GATE exam/ or of CS topic. Actually, SO is a global hit, so it's effect in India is common to be found/seen...

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, technically, everything is copyrighted or has sort of copyright attachment to it even if they are allowing it under a permissive license such as GPL, CC, etc..

I would also suggest you reading the [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal). Look for any "Exclusive Copyright" or "All Rights Reserved" related stuff. If exists, then you must adhere those terms and conditions. Also, if a copyright issue occurs, usually the original copyright holder i.e. Stack Exchange, Inc. will send a [DMCA takedown notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Copyright_Infringement_Liability_Limitation_Act) to them. Also, read the [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) page.

I would suggest reading the answer (and comments too) for Who owns the [copyright to S[OFU] content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13976/who-owns-the-copyright-to-sofu-content)?. It's worth and contains lots of good information related to Copyright material.

There are many things that goes into this matter.